# Meteor React tutorial interacting with mongo not working

Tags: reactjs, meteor

I have been trying for a while to learn how to build mobile apps with Javascript, and honestly I have no idea how anyone is able to do anything. Everything is broken. Every tutorial I've tried has failed to work for some bizarre reason. I am at my wits end.

I've finally decided to try and be even simpler, and just do the most basic tutorial I can find. What could go wrong. Well, it only took 3 pages of almost no code to completely stop working. I've done [this](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/collections), and I cannot insert anything to my db. My app fetches no data. When trying to add a new task, it gets added then disappears almost immediately, with a message stating `insert failed: Method '/tasks/insert' not found` (not even an error with some traceback).

The code really couldn't be simpler:

**`// imports/api/tasks.js`**

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';

export const Tasks = new Mongo.Collection('tasks');
```

**`// imports/ui/App.js`**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { withTracker } from 'meteor/react-meteor-data'

import { Tasks } from '../api/tasks.js';

import Task from './Task.js';

// App component - represents the whole app
class App extends Component {
    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        // find the text field via the react ref
        const text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();
        Tasks.insert({ text, createdAt: new Date() });

        // Clear form
        ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value = '';
    }

    renderTasks() {
        return this.props.tasks.map((task) => (
          <Task key={task._id} task={task} />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
          <div className="container">
            <header>
              <h1>Todo List</h1>
                <form className="new-task" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} >
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        ref="textInput"
                        placeholder="Type to add new tasks"
                    />
                </form>
            </header>

            <ul>
              {this.renderTasks()}
            </ul>
          </div>
        );
    }
};

export default withTracker(() => {
  return {
    tasks: Tasks.find({}).fetch(),
  };
})(App);
```

What is wrong? What am I missing?

Comment: I can only recommend you the tutorial from Andrew Mead on Udemy (around 10$) for a lot of hours of up to date learning. I have no share with it nor do I know him but as you seem to be looking for good quality learning tutorial, I thought I would share my personnal experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial is indeed out of date and should be updated.

Background

In June 2017 there was a [big security issue with allow/deny](https://blog.meteor.com/meteor-allow-deny-vulnerability-disclosure-baf398f47b25) identified and the feature has been blocked since then.

Meteor allowed you to define client collection, that automatically synced with the server when the methods `insert`, `update`, `remove` were called on the client.

In order to control the access permissions, the [allow/deny feature was implemented](https://guide.meteor.com/security.html#allow-deny).

Now without allow/deny you will get the `insert failed: Method '/tasks/insert' not found` when classing `SomeCollectionOnClient.insert` but since this feature is obsolete (you will even get a big warning when setting it up), you need to create a server side method and call it from the client in order resolve this issue:

On the server create this method and ensure it is in the import chain from `server/main.js`:

```
new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'tasks.insert',
  validate(args) {
    // better use simpl-schema here
    if (!args.text || !args.createdAt) {
      throw new Meteor.Error('incompleteArgs', 'args are incomplete')
    }
  },
  run (args) {
    // check user permissions...
    return Tasks.insert({ text, createdAt })
  }
})
```

In your client component you can then call it via:

```
// find the text field via the react ref
const text = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.textInput).value.trim();
Meteor.call('tasks.insert', {text, createdAt: new Date()}, (err, res) => {
  // do something on err / on res
})
```

Note that this couples your component to the server side method and you may rather try to implement some containers for your pages that handle all the connection / pub-sub / method calling activity wile your components solely render content.

More to read / used in this answer:

https://guide.meteor.com/react.html

https://guide.meteor.com/security.html

https://docs.meteor.com/api/methods.html#Meteor-call

https://guide.meteor.com/methods.html#validated-method

Comment: Wonderful answer. Was away for a while so only saw it now. Thank you very much.

Comment: Though I'm a bit confused still about where to put the code. Where exactly do I create the validated method? There's also no import chain from `server/main.js` currently, so I'm not sure where to use that. I've tried what I understood but it's not working. I'll keep trying to figure it out but I'd love if you could just add a comment specifying how the code should look like, again - this is rather new to me

Comment: The Validated method should be placed in a file that will be loaded on the server. And that's also where the import chain comes into  play: import chain means that the file that contains the validated method needs to be included by the server's main.js file or any other file that is included by the server's main.js (so it is in the include chain). If it is not imported it won't be registered as a meteor method and you client's call will fail.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll try to find my way from there